# CSS specificity when Javascript modifies CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, css-specificity

What is the CSS specificity when Javascript modifies CSS?

Such as:

```
document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
```

Is it considered inline styling?

Comment: The specificity is clear `#demo`

Comment: @Kingamere: Yes, that is inline styling

Comment: @guest271314 — No. That's completely wrong.

Comment: @Quentin The CSS is set at the element `style` attribute, that carries the most weight. Can you explain how the comment is "completely wrong"?

Comment: @guest271314 — Yes … but less weight than the ID selector your comment implied would give it.

Comment: @Quentin The CSS is set at the element itself. `#demo` at the comment refers to the HTML element itself, not `#demo` CSS selector in a style sheet, which the CSS set at the element will override. `#demo` was used to refer to the HTML element because no HTML appears at the question.

Comment: Inline styles added to an element (e.g., `style="font-weight: bold;"`) always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets, and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types

Comment: @ksav, "can be thought of as having the highest specificity" not quite. `!important` increases specificity equally, so a stylesheet could override inline styles with `!important`, but inline styles could override the stylesheet by _also_ adding `!important`.

Comment: @zzzzBov You're right. I guess that's the next section of the linked document ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> CSS specificity when Javascript modifies CSS?

Exactly the same as if you modified the CSS by editing the original source code instead of using JS.

> ```
> document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
> ```

In this case, you are modifying the styles attached directly to the element.

```
<div id="demo" style="color: red">
```

So maximum specificity. ([count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity))

If you had used JS to [modify a ruleset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Using_dynamic_styling_information), then the specificity would be different.

Answer (score 3):

The `style` property on DOM nodes is essentially an accessor/mutator for the `style` attribute for those DOM nodes.

For purposes of this answer consider `node.style.color = 'red'` to be equivalent to `node.setAttribute(node.getAttribute('style') + ' color: red')`*.

With that the question can be reframed as

> What is the CSS specificity of rules in a `style` attribute?

So of course the answer is that [the spec defines this behavior](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/REC-selectors-3-20181106/#specificity)

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> ...
>
> > **Note:** the specificity of the styles specified in an HTML style attribute is described in CSS 2.1. [[CSS21]](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/).

<sub>Yo dawg, I heard you liked specs</sub>

[From CSS 2.1:](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#specificity)

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - **count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector**, 0 otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
> - count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

So the actual calculated specificity of `document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";` is `1,0,0,0`

---

<sub>* This is of course ignoring existing rules within `style`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Through JavaScript you are modifying the DOM tree ( Html File ) not the CSS file, hence it is inline styling.

Generally inline styling in this way is not frowned upon as inline styling on a static HTML document.